# Nested View collection linked to parent View Search Input

Tags: knockout.js

I have a single page app (SPA), with a main index.html "shell" page, and from this shell, when a user clicks the menu, it dynamically loads other Views (MVC Partial Views) into a "sub" div.

These "sub-views" themselves have their own viewmodel and do their own applybindings. These dynamic "sub-views" have a knockoutobservable array collection. I want when user types into the shell viewmodels' search input, to filter the currently loaded ViewModel's knockoutobservable array.

I have found may similar questions and a good article here - http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html - but I feel this question is a different twist because each menu click will dynamically load a new View/VM, so the search input will need to un-bind, re-bind.

Here's some **psuedo-code**

Index.html Shell-

```
<div id="shell">
  <ul id="menu" data-bind="foreach: menu">
    <li><a data-bind="text:name, attr: { href: href }, click:$root.loadView" /></li>
    <li><a data-bind="text:name, attr: { href: href }, click:$root.loadView" /></li>
  </ul>
  <input id="search" type="search" data-bind="textInput:searchWords" />

    <!-- ------------------------------------------ -->
    <!-- where sub-content is dynamically loaded to -->  
    <!-- ------------------------------------------ -->    
    <div id="sub-view" data-bind="html: subView"></div>


</div>

<script>
function shellViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.menu = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'ViewA', href: "/path/to/viewA" },
        { name: 'ViewB', href: "/path/to/viewB" }
    ]);
    self.searchWords = ko.observable("");

    self.subView = ko.observable("");
    self.loadView = function(menu) {
            $.ajax({
                url: menu.href,
                success: (theView) => {
                    this.subView(theView);
                }
            });
            return false; 
        }
};

ko.applyBindings(new shellViewModel());
</script>
```

ViewA.html:

```
<div id="A">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
function viewModelA() {
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Denise' }
    ]);

    // TIE self.people to shell.searchWords
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModelA(), document.getElementById("A"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I always recommend *not* doing more than one `ko.applyBindings`, except in special circumstances.

In this case; you don't need to separately apply bindings; you'll want to add a property to your `shellViewModel` (nitpick, capitalize your VM constructors) that holds the active ViewModel, e.g. `subViewModel` to match your current `subView` property.

You can keep your template pretty much the same, but use a `with` binding so that it refers to the subViewModel.

```
<div id="A" data-bind="with: subViewModel"> <!-- assuming no intervening layers between this and root; otherwise $root.subViewModel -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As for the JS side of things; I'd recommend you use something like requireJS to manage your files, but it's not strictly necessary.  You *could* leave your code as it is, directly embedded in the templates, and you'd only need to make a few changes.

In the index.html, you'll need to make the shell a global variable that can be referenced elsewhere.  (Again, requireJS would let you avoid global variables like this) So:

```
function shellViewModel () {
     //omitted
}

shellVM = new shellViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(shellVM);
```

Then in your logic for loading ViewModelA:

```
function viewModelA() {

}
shell.subViewModel(new viewModelA());
```

Comment: In my example, the subView property was the raw html from the ajax call, basically everything you see in the second code block in my question.  The html in your answer, where are would this be still in a separate file loaded dynamically? You are saying to have a property in the shellViewModel should instead be the viewmodel instance - where does this get instantiated? And destroyed?

Comment: Yeah; I misread your example.  But yeah, you should have a property in your `shellViewModel` that holds the active ViewModel, just as `subView` holds the current view html.  You'll want to load it when you first load the view; and then you can either hold onto it for reuse, or let it fall out of scope and get garbage collected when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I still don't think your solution would work for my purposes but maybe I'm confused.. Each view will have different HTML, and it's own view model.  Say they are 100 links in the menu for 100 views/viewmodels,and they're all different - with the common factor being they all have a collection I want to tie to the search input in the shell. I can't put the Views in the index.html shell with "with" bindings - they are too complex and it would be a mess.  Where would the view get ajax loaded, and then bound to its viewmodel?

Comment: You've got a number of ways to do it.  Honestly, you should really look into something like requireJS for managing the asyncronous loading of files; what you're currently doing - embedding your ViewModel logic right in the template - is something of an antipattern.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: I am using requirejs, in the loaded view. What pattern would you recommend? That is kind of part of the answer I am hoping for...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean that you're using it "in the loaded view"; you should be using it to control view loading; that's what it does.

Comment: But honestly, I think I've answered your question here.  Create a subViewModel property on the main view.  Set the subViewModel property when the subView is loaded.  Reference the subViewModel property in your template.  That's my answer.  If you want to open another question about how to use requirejs to organize your views, go for it; but I don't care to rewrite the my above answer into requireJS syntax; I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: I'm not asking you to add requirejs. I missed along the way setting the shell viewModel.subViewModel property from the child view/viewmodel and that was the missing link in your answer I was not getting. So your answer is essentially to make the parent VM a global variable. That's kind of where I was stuck when I asked this question hoping for a better solution; I know it is because of the design I have. Anyways, thanks for your input.